# How to copy string from Tmux in an easy way on macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

On macOS, if use bash or zsh shell, use Ctrl+C can copy string to clipboard immediately. But at Tmux model, it can’t. Should press option key, then use mouse select string, press Ctrl+C. It’s a little complex. Is there a short way to do if set any option in Tmux config?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on http://apple.stackexchange.com OR http://SuperUser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: @shellter I think this topic doesn’t matter at so since it’s about tmux also related to programming. Just about configuration of that tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `tmux = terminal multiplexor`: some terminals inside another terminal. If `Ctrl+C` works when `zsh` is inside a native terminal (`iTerm` or `xterm`), but `Ctrl+C` doesn't work when `zsh` is inside `tmux`; then, that `Ctrl+C` is the feature of that native terminal (`iTerm` or `xterm`) not a feature of `zsh` or `bash`.

It is impossible to assign a same key shortcut for BOTH native terminal (`iTerm` or `xterm`) AND `tmux` (which runs inside THAT `iterm` or `xterm`).

If you prefer to use `tmux` (nearly) all the time, then you have to disable `Ctrl+C` key shortcut in the native terminal (`iTerm` or `xterm`), then set it in `tmux`. But I think most of users wont do that. They have to select a different set of key shortcuts for `tmux` without changing the native terminal settings, which they already get used to for long time.